# Best way to store continuous data in Android

Tags: android, primitive-types, data-storage, continuous-delivery

In my Android application, there will be one service which will be generating some data (statistics) like (int, time, long, boolean).

So my question is: what is the best and optimal way to save that data? (Like in DB or file, etc.)

Note: My app can't send data to any server, that data will be used in future by the application for some use case.

Comment: What is count of data? is it huge ?

Comment: If all your variables are primitive types you can use Shared Preferences: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: and how often will the data be generated?

Comment: @AndresL ,@Pankaj : Data will be like for each second 1 value of each data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at Shared Preferences.

Here [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: In my app data will be like for each second 1 value of each data, so will shared pref handle that huge amount of data??

Comment: You mean for every one second,new generated data will be stored?Whats the type of these datas?Integer,String,binary data such as map?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type and use of data

if the number of data is limited then you can use Shared Preference.

if your data contains bulk information like log or informations, you can use file. or if the field of data is limited you can also synchonize to file after storing to object.

IF the data has many fields or the amount is huge or there will be lots of add/edit/delete option then I think the best option is to use SqliteDatabase